# Differences in webtool and standalone Clustal Omega Percent Identity Matrix

Tags: sequence-alignment

I'm trying to align sequences using MUSCLE in my own computer. To compute Percent Identity Matrix I'm trying to use Clustal2.1 like it's done in https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/msa/muscle/. Even though I'm doing the same thing, I get rounded up values in my computer.

For example, this is the webtool output:

```
#
#
#  Percent Identity  Matrix - created by Clustal2.1 
#
#

     1: JX310755.1  100.00   92.79   65.29   63.98
     2: M97264.1     92.79  100.00   65.66   63.92
     3: AJ292230.1   65.29   65.66  100.00   66.88
     4: KM379144.1   63.98   63.92   66.88  100.00
```

And this is the output in my computer.

```
#
#
#  Percent Identity  Matrix - created by Clustal2.1 
#
#

     1: JX310755.1     100      93      65      64
     2: M97264.1        93     100      66      64
     3: AJ292230.1      65      66     100      67
     4: KM379144.1      64      64      67     100
```

I have both installed clustalw using `sudo apt install clustalw` and by downloading the tarballs from http://www.clustal.org/download/current/clustalw-2.1.tar.gz, with exact results.

The commmand I'm using is `clustalw2 alignment -tree -pim`.

Any thoughts on why this could be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a year I came out with the solution - as M__ kindly suggested, using Clustal Omega.

First, align usign muscle:

`muscle -in fasta -quiet -out alignment`

Then, generate percent distance matrix using clustal omega:

`clustalo --infile alignment --distmat-out output --percent-id --full`

Answer (score 1):

Try clustal omega, instead of clustalw because it is really old. It should report to 2 dp. Variations do occur depending on how indels are treated, but this is just rounding.

You could try

```
alignment -tree -pim -score
```

The idea is to convert to absolute rather than percentage and might overcome the rounding error